# xampp warning message

Tags: xampp

i have installed Apache server on my computer,

when i try to enter the university registration system,

this message comes to me:

```
Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
***.***.**.** : ip
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

what is the problem?

Comment: note, that i'am using win8

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your localhost is not visible online on www 
1.Learn to make your localhost visible on Internet
2.Portforward in case
3.Test online

check out all 3 demos from [GO ONLINE](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_online_open_port.html) menu